# How rotate a needle in semicircle?

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

[image: This is What I want]
I want to rotate a needle when user input weight.
The low value and high value is dynamically changed by user's height.

```
pointer.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(weight / low * .pi / 3))
```

This code is working at under low side.
But I don't know how to point low ~ high , over high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to convert `weight` to a value between `0` and `1` to get a "progress" value. You can do this by using an `inverseLerp` function, it would look something like this:

```
let progress = (weight - low) / (high - low)
```

This formula will return 0 when `weight == low` and 1 when `weight == high`.

Now you have to convert that into a rotation. Assuming that the image of your arrow is pointing up by default, we'll need to rotate in a range of `[-pi / 2, pi / 2]`. `pi` is half a rotation, so we're doing a quarter of a rotation to the left, and a quarter to the right.

A `lerp` function turns a value in the range `[0, 1]`, like the one we already have, into a value inside a range, which is just what we need. It looks like this:

```
let value = (1 - progress) * start + progress * end
```

Using actual values, it would look like this:

```
let angle = (1 - progress) * (-.pi / 2) + progress * (.pi / 2)
```

We now use that to transform our arrow view:

```
pointer.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

Views will rotate by the center by default, because this is where their [`anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint) is located by default. Since we want our view to rotate around the bottom middle of its frame, we can change it like this:

```
pointer.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(0.5, 1)
```

This should rotate our view like we want it to.

PS: I made a library called `CGMath` that includes functions like this. You can [check it out here](https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/CGMath).

Comment: You should update the Readme to say that pod installation is no longer needed.